# Rails: how to combine likes notification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the case: user could be notified when his topic is repied and liked.

Dealing `replies` is easy. When one reply is created, it will create a notification to the author of the topic.

However, when dealing with `likes`, there are always more people doing it. So I need to combine the notifications of likes. So user could be notified like `Mike and 7 other have liked your topic`.

The problem is that, now I modelling `notification` as polymorphic.

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subject, polymorphic: true # could be reply, likes and others
end
```

So the relationship goes like `reply`->`notification`->`user`, which is 1 to 1 to 1.

I display `@notifcations` by `@notifications.each`, to iterate through them.

But one notification can only represent one like(by the `subject_id`), that's too many for `likes`, since too many people use this feature.

So I want to combine the notification. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't get you, you need just get number of notifications from reply, like `reply.notificaitons.size` and get the first user who 'liked'? So it will be the two queries: count + first user through subject.

Comment: @DmitryPolushkin, How do you display notifications? I do by `@notification.all.each`, to iterate through them. But one `notification` can only represent one like(by the `subject_id`). But that is too many for `likes`, since too many people use this feature. So I want to combine the notification. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you only need to count the likes? like this: `Notification.where(subject_type: 'like', subject_id: SOME_ID).size` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you , and then record the time the last notification was shown (for instance, a cron job which checks every hour, or when the user looks at notifications in the UI), probably as a column on the user model.

Then, when you run your notification tasks, filter by the created-by date being more than the last notification

```
likes = @topic.likes.where('created_at > ?', @user.last_notified_at)
```

Does this answer your question?